Find all sequence that satisfy the system of equation

Find all real numbers $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_n$ such that
\begin{cases}
    \sqrt{a_1^3-a_2}=a_3-1\\
    \sqrt{a_2^3-a_3}=a_4-1\\
    \vdots\\
    \sqrt{a_{n-1}^3-a_n}=a_1-1\\
    \sqrt{a_n^3-a_1}=a_2-1
\end{cases}

I try to square both side and add them all together. This give me
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i^3-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i-n=0$
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_i^3-a_i^2+a_i-1)=0 $
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_i-1)(a_i^2+1)=0 $
And I get an answer of $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots =a_n=1$
But I can neither find more nor prove that this is the only solution.

You've made a great start, and actually almost have it. Since the $a_i$ are real numbers, the LHS equations' square roots must all be non-negative real values. We then get from the RHS of your equations for all $1 \le i \le n$ that
$$a_i - 1 \ge 0 \;\;\to\;\; (a_i - 1)(a_i^2 + 1) \ge 0$$
This means
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i - 1)(a_i^2 + 1) \ge 0$$
with it being equal to $0$ iff each summation term is $0$ so, since $a_i^2 + 1 \ge 1$, we must have $a_i - 1 = 0$, i.e.,
$$a_i = 1 \;\forall\; 1 \le i \le n$$
As such, since this also satisfies all of the constraint equations, this shows that you have found the only solution.
